# PTIJ: Why isn't every day of the year called "Purim"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Esther 9:27 says:

> על כן קראו לימים האלה פורים על שם הפור

"Therefore, they called these days (14 and 15 of Adar) "Purim" to commemorate the poor."

Why should the name "Purim" be limited to just those two days of the year? Isn't there a mitzvah to give tzedaka / assist the poor each day? Shouldn't we commemorate the poor, daily, so every day should be called "Purim"?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Mitzvah of Matanos Laevyonim (and Kol Haposhet) netting all of the poor people so much money, after two days of Purim, no one is poor anymore, so we cannot name the day after poor people.  This lasts all the way until the next year...

Comment: You're schnorring too much :-)